# Cannot get go packages

Tags: go, windows-10, go1.14

It seems the packages won't install in my Windows 10.

Go is already in the path, and its version is:

```
C:\Proyectos\gcloud-app>go version
go version go1.14.2 windows/amd64
```

But the `go get` does not work:

```
C:\Proyectos\gcloud-app>go get github.com/gin-gonic/gin
# runtime/internal/atomic
c:\go\src\runtime\internal\atomic\atomic_amd64x.go:18:6: Load redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at c:\go\src\runtime\internal\atomic\atomic_amd64.go:16:24
c:\go\src\runtime\internal\atomic\atomic_amd64x.go:24:6: Loadp redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at c:\go\src\runtime\internal\atomic\atomic_amd64.go:22:32
c:\go\src\runtime\internal\atomic\atomic_amd64x.go:30:6: Load64 redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at c:\go\src\runtime\internal\atomic\atomic_amd64.go:28:26
c:\go\src\runtime\internal\atomic\atomic_amd64x.go:36:6: LoadAcq redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at c:\go\src\runtime\internal\atomic\atomic_amd64.go:34:27
c:\go\src\runtime\internal\atomic\atomic_amd64x.go:41:6: Xadd redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at c:\go\src\runtime\internal\atomic\atomic_amd64.go:39:37
c:\go\src\runtime\internal\atomic\atomic_amd64x.go:44:6: Xadd64 redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at c:\go\src\runtime\internal\atomic\atomic_amd64.go:42:39
c:\go\src\runtime\internal\atomic\atomic_amd64x.go:47:6: Xadduintptr redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at c:\go\src\runtime\internal\atomic\atomic_amd64.go:45:47
c:\go\src\runtime\internal\atomic\atomic_amd64x.go:50:6: Xchg redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at c:\go\src\runtime\internal\atomic\atomic_amd64.go:48:36
c:\go\src\runtime\internal\atomic\atomic_amd64x.go:53:6: Xchg64 redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at c:\go\src\runtime\internal\atomic\atomic_amd64.go:51:38
c:\go\src\runtime\internal\atomic\atomic_amd64x.go:56:6: Xchguintptr redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at c:\go\src\runtime\internal\atomic\atomic_amd64.go:54:45
c:\go\src\runtime\internal\atomic\atomic_amd64x.go:56:6: too many errors
```

What would be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I installed 1.14 over an older version. So there was some sort of issue related to files that supposed to be removed from go installation folder during a new install.

I have to manually remove `c:\go` installation folder and repair installation.

Also, I removed older packages from `c:\users\%username%\go`.

Now the installation has no warnings

```
C:\Proyectos\gcloud-app>go get -u github.com/gin-gonic/gin
```